# How to do VLOOKUP with a list of values

Tags: excel

I have two sheet in excel.
In sheet2 I have a table with these fields:
NAME, SURNAME, CITY, AGE

In sheet1 I have to set field CITY and I want that table under this field will be with all the rows from sheet2 with selected CITY.

If I do a VLOOKUP I obioubsly get only first row of table.

Example:

```
A      | B       | C       | D 
NAME   | SURNAME | CITY    | AGE
Alex   | Green   | Rome    | 18
Max    | Brown   | Rome    | 21
Mary   | White   | Milan   | 33
George | Violet  | Rome    | 27
```

In sheet 1 I have

```
A      | B       | C       | D
CITY   | Rome
NAME   | SURNAME | CITY    | AGE
VLOOKUP| VLOOKUP | VLOOKUP | VLOOKUP
VLOOKUP| VLOOKUP | VLOOKUP | VLOOKUP

VLOOKUP = VLOOKUP($B$2;Sheet2!A:D;1;0) -->
```

I wanted ALEX, MAX, GEORGE; I have ALEX, ALEX, ALEX

How can I do this without macros?

Thank you

Comment: Advanced Filter?

Comment: Otherwise it will be a whole bunch of Array Type of formulas that depending on your data size will cause a large slow down in calculations at as some point may even crash Excel.

Comment: And `VLOOKUP` doesn't work either- "Rome" would have to be in Column A on Sheet2.

Comment: Why the aversion to vba, as using Advanced Filter in a Worksheet_Change event will be quick and automatic.

Comment: I don't have Excel on this PC to check, but you can use OFFSET() and ROW() functions to move down the column so you don't always select ALEX

Answer (score 0):

For a simple data configuration like your sample pu this in Sheet1!A3 and fill both right and down,

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$9)/(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$9=$B$1),ROW(1:1)))
```

For more complicated data configurations and retrievals put this in Sheet1!A3 and fill right and down,

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$D, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$9)/(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$9=$B$1), ROW(1:1)), MATCH(A$2, Sheet2!$1:$1, 0))
```

[image]

Use an IFERROR function 'wrapper' to avoid displaying worksheet errors when you run out of data to retrieve.

Comment: It does work. Just a little thing: the real table have 5000 rows. I was able only to extract first 9 rows. If I change ROW($2:$9) INTO ROW($2:$5000) AND Sheet2!$C$2:C$9 INTO Sheet2!$C$2:C$5000 it does no work. How can I do?